Is there a way for me to get the Album Art of the song currently playing using the Spotify Web API, and return a png of the album art
I am trying to make a python script that changes my discord background to the cover art of the song currently playing. I am using a program called "Better Discord" that allows me to change the background to any image I want. The line in the file that controls the background looks like this:
--background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/jVNPMHp.png'); /* Main background image | URL MUST BE A DIRECT LINK (ending in .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif) */
I have the Spotify Web API and am trying to use it to get a png of the album art. Here is the code I have so far:
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import re
import time

def get_current_song_art():
    # Initialize Spotify client
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="da859753510c43ebb6b65ef975195a7b",
                                                   client_secret="325ace4499d141598710563b21c7424d",
                                                   redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888/callback",
                                                   scope="user-read-currently-playing"))

    # Get currently playing song
    current_song = sp.current_playback()

    # Extract album art URL from currently playing song
    if current_song and current_song['is_playing'] and current_song['item']:
        album_art_url = current_song['item']['album']['images'][0]['url']
        return album_art_url
    else:
        return None

def update_css_file(album_art_url, css_file_path):
    # Read CSS file
    with open(css_file_path, 'r') as file:
        css_content = file.read()

    # Update background-image property
    updated_css_content = re.sub(r'--background-image:\s*url\(.*?\);', f'--background-image: url(\'{album_art_url}\');', css_content)

    # Write updated CSS content back to file
    with open(css_file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(updated_css_content)

def main():
    # File path to FrostedGlass.theme
    css_file_path = "FrostedGlass.theme"

    while True:
        # Get current song album art
        album_art_url = get_current_song_art()

        # If album art URL is available, update CSS file
        if album_art_url:
            update_css_file(album_art_url, css_file_path)

        # Sleep for some time before checking again
        time.sleep(10)  # Adjust as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

this is bringing back this error:
`HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player with Params: {'market': None, 'additional_types': None} returned 401 due to Permissions missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unrut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 271, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\unrut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unrut\change.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\unrut\change.py", line 41, in main
    album_art_url = get_current_song_art()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\unrut\change.py", line 14, in get_current_song_art
    current_song = sp.current_playback()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\unrut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 1757, in current_playback
    return self._get("me/player", market=market, additional_types=additional_types)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\unrut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 323, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\unrut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 293, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 401, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player:
 Permissions missing, reason: None
`I have the correct Client ID and Secret ID, and my redirect URI is http://discord-changer-login://callback

I am not quite sure what the problem is. From the research I did, the WebPlayer scope isn't properly installed? However, I am not sure where I need to initialize that scope or what I can do to make this project easier on myself. Thank you in advance.
I tried to run that python file to continually update my discord background, however it resulted in the error listed above.
